# compare which two cube is the same

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I am solving  following problem:

[image]

The problem states  that  on figure 1 there is shown a cube with three facets on which there is drawn three section(length).  This cube was put on other facet and turned such that there is also shown these three  length  on one cube from list of cubes which are drawn below.our task is find which one is this cube?please help  i think that D,E,and C is not, in my point of view it must be A but not sure.

Comment: Try to rotate the cube in your mind (or get a dice and actually do it). You are right that D, E and C are not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is incorrect. Pretend you are standing on the line segment which touches a corner of the cube. Orient yourself so you are facing the this corner. Then the line which touches the side is to your left, but on $A$ it is to the right. So the answer can't be $A.$

The answer is $B.$ See if once you know the answer you have an easier time about the spacial reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

B but D is not wrong because of the hidden sides

Comment: Since there are three hidden sides, any could be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take a paper and some glue and verify that your thoughts are correct.

Comment: "Protip" - ??? I guess if we're not allowed to upvote our answers, that's the next best thing...

Comment: Maybe I should have called it hint. Actually thats a method to solve also very hard problems of that kind, of course it is cheating but it can be used to control the result.

Comment: This is a very good method to get precisely one question right on the SAT.

Comment: @jspecter: I didn't say this method is good to apply it in a math test, its rather didactical.

Comment: @Listing: That's not cheating; it's a legit problem-solving strategy!